# Take really quick screenshots of Android Phone programmatically

Tags: android, screenshot

I am taking screenshots of an Android phone from my application by this code

```
                java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > " + raw + "\n");
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                process.waitFor();
```

But when I put this in a service, and try to run infinitely, I get atmost 2 screenshots.

**Is there a way to take screenshots really quick? Like 15-20 in a second using ANY way possible?**

EDIT : I try to convert them to video later. Any way to make video without dumping it to the file altogether?

Comment: Probably not if you are trying to write them to a file, as you are trying to here. Screenshots are several MB in size, and flash storage is not very fast.

Comment: @CommonsWare any way to do it without dumping it to the file?

Comment: Not for your intended purpose, unless you are looking for a very short video.

Comment: Did you found something @Kay